# Would splitting a query by an indexed ID field avoid ORA-01555: snapshot too old error?

Tags: sql, oracle, rollbacksegments

I have some queries of the form:

```
select * from MAIN.MY_TABLE 
    where ID in (select ID from OTHER.OTHER_TABLE where type = 'BANANA');
```

Where `ID` is indexed on `MAIN.MYTABLE`, but not indexed on `OTHER.OTHER_TABLE`

Recently these have been erroring with `ORA-01555: snapshot too old`.

My understanding is this this due to the query taking too long for the undo space.

This is likely to be due it being peak business season and the databases being under heavy load.

The question is, if I were to split the query into the several queries of the form:

```
select * from MAIN.MY_TABLE 
    where ID in (select ID from OTHER.OTHER_TABLE where type = 'BANANA') 
        and ID >= 0 and ID <1000;

select * from MAIN.MY_TABLE 
    where ID in (select ID from OTHER.OTHER_TABLE where type = 'BANANA') 
        and ID >= 1000 and ID <2000;

select * from MAIN.MY_TABLE 
    where ID in (select ID from OTHER.OTHER_TABLE where type = 'BANANA') 
        and ID >= 2000 and ID <3000;
```

On one hand this seems like each query would take less time than initial query. On the otherhand, it seems like such an obvious optimisation, that I would think that Oracle would do this anyway.

Comment: Its also faster to place your second sql in a procedure where minimum and maximum id as parameter.

Comment: Do you use ASSM (automatic segment space management)?

Comment: what is the value of undo_retention parameter? What are the # of rows in both tables? Is type in other_table indexed? How many rows do you expect? How much space does the undo tablespace have? What else happens at those moments in the database (modifications)?

Comment: @ik_zelf - I'm just a end user of the database, and don't have a access to a lot of information about it. The DBAs are hard to get hold of, there are three for an organisation of around 5000.

Comment: If your problem solves a business problem, I expect it will be solved by giving you the right resources. For now: No, the split won't help. Without the requested info no valid answers.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try optimising the query so it doesn't take so long? For starters, Oracle can have some difficulty building a good query plan if you use IN (SELECT...) instead of a join. Does this query return the same result with a better query plan (i.e. a `JOIN` operator instead of an `IN` operator):

```
select * from MAIN.MY_TABLE 
inner join
OTHER.OTHER_TABLE 
on MAIN.MY_TABLE.ID = OTHER.OTHER_TABLE.ID
and OTHER.OTHER_TABLE.type = 'BANANA';
```

The only issue is if you have duplicates in `OTHER.OTHER_TABLE` on the `ID` column. This will result in double counting in the final result set. But you should really avoid that kind of `IN (SELECT....)` structure if possible.

Comment: In general Oracle will not have difficulty building a good plan with such a simple query - subquery unnesting works well in this case.  For example, I built a simple example [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/98880/1) and the plans are almost identical between the two versions.  (Note that this SQLFiddle doesn't work well.  It doesn't parse the `explain plan for` correctly, you'd need to run it locally to see the real plans.)

Answer (score 1):

How many rows this query suppose to return comparing to number of rows in MY_TABLE?

Index on MY_TABLE.ID will help if number of rows in number of rows in (select distinct ID from OTHER.OTHER_TABLE where type = 'BANANA') ~2-5% of number of rows in MY_TABLE.

So I'd check that numbers first. And I would try query like this:

```
select * 
from MAIN.MY_TABLE a,
     (select distinct ID from OTHER.OTHER_TABLE where type = 'BANANA') b
where a.id = b.id;
```

If true, and index on MY_TABLE is used (according to execution plan), I'd check how fast (select distinct ID from OTHER.OTHER_TABLE where type = 'BANANA') is executed:

```
select count(1)
from
(select distinct ID from OTHER.OTHER_TABLE where type = 'BANANA')
```

P.S.
To get real execution plan in sqlplus:

```
set linesize 200
set autotrace traceonly
    select * 
    from MAIN.MY_TABLE a,
         (select distinct ID from OTHER.OTHER_TABLE where type = 'BANANA') b
    where a.id = b.id;
```

Comment: Perhaps around 100m records on MY_TABLE and 10m records on OTHER_TABLE

Comment: It's important how many records are returned by `(select distinct ID from OTHER.OTHER_TABLE where type = 'BANANA')`. The size of table OTHER_TABLE itself affects only this subquery.

Comment: Yes-  10m returned by the subquery.